# Identity relating Bayes risk to bias

Tags: self-study, bayesian, mathematical-statistics

> Let $X\sim f(x\mid \theta)$ and $\theta\sim \pi(\theta)$. The Bayes estimator under squared error loss is $\delta^\pi(x)=E(\theta\mid x)$. How do i show that the Bayes risk of $\delta^\pi$ can be written
>   $$
> r(\pi,\delta^\pi)=\int_\Theta \theta b(\theta)\pi(\theta)\,\,d\theta,
> $$
>   where $b(\theta)=E[\delta^\pi(X)\mid\theta]-\theta$.

I tried writing
\begin{align*}
r(\pi,\delta^\pi)&=\int R(\theta,\delta^\pi)\pi(\theta)d\theta \\
&=\int E_\theta(\theta-\delta^\pi( X))^2\pi(\theta)d\theta.
\end{align*}
So now we have to show $E_\theta(\theta-\delta^\pi( X))^2 = \theta b(\theta)$, but 
$$
E_\theta(\theta-\delta^\pi( X))^2 = var [\delta^\pi(X)] + b(\theta)^2.
$$
Is this the right approach? Not really sure how to proceed from here.

This is exercise 4.2.5 from Lehmann/Casella and taken from the paper by Dasgupta (1994) http://www.stat.purdue.edu/docs/research/tech-reports/1994/tr94-16.pdf (page 15)